# Cannot resolve configuration property 'hystrix.command.messages.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds'

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul

I am new to Spring boot with Zuul Api Gateway.When I declare the Timeout  properties for zuul in application.properties file, it is not picking up.I Guess I have missed some library.

These are the configuration I have added and set to 60 sec timeout.
hystrix.command.messages.execution.isolation.strategy=THREAD
hystrix.command.messages.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds= 100000
ribbon.readtimeout=60000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=60000

And these are the Lib

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-zuul</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=100000`

`ribbon.ReadTimeout=100000`

`ribbon.ConnectTimeout=100000`

override ***ribbon.ReadTimeout*** and ***ribbon.ConnectTimeout*** as well with ***hystrix.command*** property.

use **default** for global setting. use the **service-id** instead for service level setting.

Answer (score 0):

Change to this :

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=
```

Comment: Still the same... Gateway Timeout

Comment: override ribbon.ReadTimeout and ribbon.ConnectTimeout as well with this.

Answer (score 0):

Below entry in application.yaml resolved my problem.

```
hystrix:  
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 100000
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

`ribbon.ReadTimeout` default timeout is 1s, and overtime ribbon will retry onetime, so you will see in the provider project get twice request. If use `@HystrixCommand` you should reset it.

For example:

```
ribbon.ReadTimeout=5000 and ribbon.ConnectTimeout=5000;
```